# Can I control which screen XFCE shows the alt-tab switcher on?

Tags: xfce, application-switcher

I'm trying to transition from Gnome to XFCE and when I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to cycle between windows, the list of windows shows on the wrong screen (I have an nvidia card with twinview spanning the desktop over an LCD and my TV.)

Can this be controlled? Ideally it would always display on the LCD only, failing that, can I disable it but keep <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> functional?

Comment: According to the [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/119528/236) this was a bug which was fixed in 12.04. So I'll close this question.

Comment: See this [related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220165/switch-windows-only-in-current-workspace-and-display).