# How to save and restore working environment, each app in a virtual desktop (including browsers with tabs)?

Tags: virtualdesktop

Is there a ready solution for saving and restoring whole working environment?

I want to save a project's workspace, and restore it inside a virtual desktop:

- browsers (with their own tabs)
- other apps (any app that was there in that desktop and can be automatically started)
- possibly terminal sessions (i'm not greedy, though)

Why:

I want to be recover my workspace after a restart for any reason, e.g. power drain, accidental crash, multi-boot, etc.)

Or to "save" an entire project and load it at another time.

I'm not looking for perfect solutions, but the more - the better.

(P.S. I know of "screen" and alike for terminal sessions.  This is not the big issue here)

Answer (score 1):

There is not a ready solution in standard Ubuntu, which uses Gnome Shell. Even basic session saving, i.e., where you can save your desktop state such that it is restored after a reboot, has been dropped because it had issues. Other desktops may provide session saving, but usually will not allow you to save different states. However, KDE desktop probably does.

You are looking for an even more refined experience, where you can save desktop states depending on what project/activity you want to continue. This is actually what KDE desktop provides through their "Activities" function. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253990/what-is-a-activity-in-kde-and-what-can-i-do-with-it), although quite old already, gives you an idea what these "Activities" are about. So it may be worthy to explore the KDE desktop environment to see how well it fits what you are after.

Comment: lucky me, i'm already using KDE

Comment: So explore the "Activities" option and tell us if indeed it meets your search. If it does, then please consider accepting this answer.